# Should I explain it is not retaliation?

Tags: team, meetings

**Context:**

My team leader, with hierarchical and project responsibilities, has problems with my team. To be clear and concise, most of the team is jealous of one, namely Bob. Because Bob is often selected for interesting tasks, and more boring (but very important) tasks are for the rest of the team.

**Events:**

Yesterday, Bob was selected in the team by drawing lots for a specific, interesting task. Chief chose to draw lots to avoid a touchy choice. Tomorrow, I organize a meeting with my team leader, about a totally different point than the project Bob was selected for. But the meeting is basically about me and a co-worker complaining.

**Problem:**

I think this, and other similar events, could be interpreted in the long run as "retaliation" from the team about how Bob is treated.
Should I make clear with team leader that there I (at least) am entirely professionnal, or try to, and that there is no sort of retaliation for the true problem about Bob?

Comment: Mind giving a bit more background? What do you mean "the way Bob is treated"? You say this was by random choice, how can people be jealous or think you are retaliating? Has there been other special treatment in the past?

Comment: I have a very hard time following your post. Would you mind structuring it a bit more? Who did what? When? What is the problem?

Comment: Right I'll edit the question because I was not clear (so evident since I'm living that): Bob is favoured in having some tasks, so yesterday chief, to avoid favouring someone, chose to draw lots. Most of the team is ok with that

Comment: The second paragraph sounds like you and a co-worker are planning on using false pretenses to trick your team-lead into a meeting where you complain about Bob. Is that how you intended it?

Comment: It's still unclear to me how having a meeting is retaliation against Bob. Is the meeting to complain about Bob? If so, is it about something Bob did or about something else Bob got that the rest of you didn't? (Very pedantic nitpick: y'all are experiencing envy not jealousy.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone is directly accusing you of "retaliation", there is nothing for you to explain to anyone.

If you are behaving in a way that you feel could be interpreted as retaliation for something then you need to take a step back and ask yourself if you are behaving in a professional manner.  For starters, complaining with your co-worker about another employee is typically not a professional behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I don't feel I retaliate and I 'm not complaining about other co workers in the meeting. But I feel like the meeting I create could be felt as "you prefer Bob? Then I'll do minimal tasks only"